# SqlAlchemy assign different column name for ColumnClause

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using sqlachemy in my Django application for complex query execution,

As you can see in the following code, I assign `user` as the variable name of table `user_backup`.

How can I do the same thing for column? Example assign variable name `description2` to `something_long`

```
from sqlalchemy import table, column, select

user = table("user_backup",
        column("id"),
        column("name"),
        column("description"),
        column("something_long"),
)

stmt = select([user.c.description]).where(user.c.name == 'wendy')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just assign it.

```
description2 = user.c.description
```